# Not able to add values to a dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary -> `var dictionary = [String : [String]]()` and I want to append string values in the array of the dictionary. This is how I'm doing it

```
 for (key, value) in dictionary {
  dictionary.updateValue(value.append(nameText),forKey: "name")
}
```

Here, `nameText` is a string, I'm getting an error saying,

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'value' is a 'let' constant.

What am I doing wrong? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This code has indeterminate behaviour. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is that `value` is a `let` constant within your loop body. You must declare it as `var` in order to mutate it.

Your second issue is that you're trying to use `value.append(nameText)` as the value to set for the key. However, `append()` mutates the array in place, and returns `Void`.

Thirdly, don't use `updateValue(forKey:)`. There's really no point. Use subscripting instead.

```
var dictionary = [
    "a" : ["a"],
    "b" : ["b", "b"],
    "c" : ["c", "c", "c"],
]

let nameText = "foo"
for (key, var value) in dictionary {
    value.append(nameText)
    dictionary["name"] = value
}
```

Now, this gets your code to *compile*, but I'm highly skeptical this is really what you want to do. You'll be overwriting the value for the `"name"` key on every iteration, meaning only the last iteration's value will persist. Furthermore, because `Dictionary` doesn't have a defined ordering, this code has indeterminate behaviour. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: What my objective is to build a dictionary something like this -> `[name: [all different names], address: [all different address], gender: [all genders]]`. My dictionary looks something like that -> ` var dictionary = [String : [String]]()`

Comment: Firstly I have to ask, why are you using a dictionary to store data with static keys?

Comment: What would you suggest?

Comment: Using structs or classes. Dictionaries are really clunky for storing staticky keyed data

Comment: Would this `var value` approach induce an extra copy overhead as compared to mutating the the inner array in-place (`dictionary.keys.forEach { dictionary[$0]?.append(nameText) }`)? The latter might need to move the array, but maybe there's an equivalent copy "overhead" in that approach as well.

Comment: This would almost certainly cause a copy, unless the compiler optimized it. However, your approach is equally susceptible, as ultimately it's just a facade over a read-modify-write operation, in which the "modify" entails "copy" due to value semantics.

Comment: That sounds plausible. Btw, don't forget tagging (@) when answering comments (except when commenting to the author of an answer or question that owns the comments, in which case they're redundant), I almost missed your answer to my comment as SO didn't notify me about it :)

Comment: @dfri Whoops. Nice catch. But yeah, If you have the time and want to fire up SIL inspector, or manually compile to assembly, I'd be curious to see a comparison of the 2 techniques

Comment: Might look into after work, or to the weekend. If so, will let you know (Y)

Comment: Interesting and very related [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079687/dictionary-in-swift-with-mutable-array-as-value-is-performing-very-slow-how-to) (especially the answer). In light of RobNapiers answer, I belive both our methods are probably to be avoided in performance tight applications, in favour of actually removing the inner value (array) prior to mutating and re-adding it to the dictionary.

Comment: @dfri Great post, and great find!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    dictionary.updateValue(value + [nameText], forKey: key)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about it for a second; `value.append(nameText)` is an **action**. It returns `Void` (the type for ... nothing!).

You want to update the value to something **upon which an action has been performed**.

Instead of *manually* making a temporary copy, modifying that, and then using it to update the value for some key, you can simply use subscripts and extensions:

What you want is:

```
extension Dictionary
{
    public subscript(forceUnwrapping key: Key) -> Value
    {
        get
        {
            return self[key]!
        }

        set
        {
            self[key] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

So, for a dictionary named `dictionary`:

```
for key in dictionary.keys
{
    dictionary[forceUnwrapping: key].append(nameText)
}
```

Specifically, `dictionary[forceUnwrapping: key].append(nameText)`.

Comment: When I do this, it is not going inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @shravan.sukumar could you elaborate on your issue? What errors are you getting?

Comment: So, it does not enter the `for` loop, not running the line `dictionary[forceUnwrapping: key].append(nameText)` which is inside the loop.

Comment: @shravan.sukumar you need to copy the `Dictionary` `extension` (in the answer) to somewhere in your code.

Comment: Yes, I did do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* example setup */
var dictionary: [String: [String]] = ["foo": [], "bar": []]
let nameText = "foobar"

/* append the value of the 'nameText' immutable to each inner array */
dictionary.keys.forEach { dictionary[$0]?.append(nameText) }

/* ok! */
print(dictionary) // ["bar": ["foobar"], "foo": ["foobar"]]
```

As described in the following Q&A, however

- [Dictionary in Swift with Mutable Array as value is performing very slow? How to optimize or construct properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079687/dictionary-in-swift-with-mutable-array-as-value-is-performing-very-slow-how-to)

..., it is good to be aware of the overhead of mutating "in place", especially if working performance tight applications. Taking the advice from the answer in the linked thread above, an alternative, more sensible and less copy-wasteful approach would be e.g.:

```
var dictionary: [String: [String]] = ["foo": [], "bar": []]
let nameText = "foobar"

dictionary.keys.forEach { 
    var arr = dictionary.removeValue(forKey: $0) ?? []
    arr.append(nameText)
    dictionary[$0] = arr
}

print(dictionary) // ["bar": ["foobar"], "foo": ["foobar"]]
```

Comment: Would it possible to add it to one the `foo` key? Rather than adding it to both the `foo` and the `bar` keys?

Comment: @shravan.sukumar if you only want to update the inner array for _one_ specific key (say `foo`), you can e.g. simply use `dictionary["foo"]?.append(nameText)`.